# Problems installing libcurl4-openssl-dev on Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, libcurl

I am trying to install libcurl4-openssl-dev on Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS.

This is the CL output when I run `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libcurl4-openssl-dev : Depends: libcurl3 (= 7.47.0-1ubuntu2) but 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How may I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem using aptitude:

`sudo aptitude -f install libcurl4-openssl-dev`

I then accepted the option to downgrade to libcurl3. The problem was solved after that.